# Retrieve git information from within an application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, version-control

I am developing an **[application](http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/view-demo)** for issue tracking and I want to do the following:

1. User provides the git base url to an activity (that has issues) like this: `host_ip:/git/repository/path`
2. Each time an issue page is shown, there will be a link that will show the commits made to the repository with a message containing the issue key.

In my development env I have it working because I execute something like:

`git --git-dir /git/repository/path log --all --grep=foo`

but this will not be the case when I deploy it to production.

I want to execute the command above but with a path that is not in the server the application is hosted.
Any ideas?

Comment: Put a copy of repo to the production?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I wanted to avoid that...

Comment: ssh? what kind of access do you have to that machine?

Comment: @phoet I'll be able to have ssh access, all required pwds can be provided when binding an activity to its repo.

Comment: @grotori storing or entering the passwords is not a good idea at all. you should use public-keys and the authorized keys system of ssh to get access to that machine.

Comment: @phoet I totally agree but I plan to integrate with svn/cvs too..

Comment: @grotori ssl does not care about svn and cvs. it's just a secure transportation layer for whatever you want to execute on a remote host.

Comment: @phoet Yes, for ssh I know what must be done but for svn/cvs there are configurations that require username/password to connect, independent of the use of ssh.

Comment: not exactly an answer, but you should have a look at [the grit gem](https://github.com/mojombo/grit). Doesn't handle remote repos AFAIK, but you could find some inspiration in the source. It's what [Gitlab](http://gitlab.org/) uses btw.

Comment: Currently, I got it working with a cloning of the to the server. You can see the functionality here: http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/feature-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I got it working with a cloning of the repo to the server.

You can see the functionality here: http://actibities-uniongr.rhcloud.com/pages/feature-log